# Types conditions on python after an input

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a beginner at programming and what I want is to place a condition in which I write a real number and want the program to tell me whether it's a fractional or an integer.

I'm starting with:

```
x = float(input("Writte a real number: "))
```

and then I thought of using a double condition in which I would do something like:

```
if type(x)==int:
    print("integer number")
```

and another one with float instead of int (or use an else, since I say before to write a real number). But I guess this isn't right since I predefine x as a float. Another problem would be the numbers like 2.0 or 3.0 since they are integer but I would get them as fractionals.

Comment: Would probably be easier to just take the input as a string, then check for the existence of a '.'

Comment: Is `print(type(ast.literal_eval(input('enter a number of some sort...')))` what you're after? That way you'll also get an exception if someone just enters `.` or something that's not a number at all...

Comment: Can't take the input as a string since I've got more conditions and some other things I want to check on the numbers which I didn't mention here (only said about the part I'm having trouble with).

I still don't know about the literal_eval command which makes it impossible for me to use.

Thanks for the replies though

Comment: @Royal it's not a massive secret about [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) :) Python has a large standard library and comprehensive documentation - it's well worth a few minutes to read if you're not sure of something instead of concluding it's impossible to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using an important property of integers: the **floor** and **ceiling** value of an integer would be the same; whereas, for a floating-point number, these values would differ by 1.

So, you could do something like:

```
import math
x = float(input("Writte a real number: "))
if math.ceil(x) == math.floor(x):
    print("integer number")
```

- The floor of a number x is the largest integer less than or equal to x.
- The ceiling of a number x is the smallest integer greater than or equal to x.

You can see some examples of floor and ceiling [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Examples).

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Carcigeniacte's comment. You can leave it as a string initially, check the conversions against each other; then if they are the same, it's an `int`, otherwise it's a `float`. After that, convert it to whichever numerical type is appropriate for the calculations later. Just don't forget to check for a bad input:

```
while True:
    x = input('write a real number: ')
    try:
        float(x)  # Checking the input can be converted to a number
        break

    except ValueError:
        print('\nPlease input a number')  # runs if it can't be converted
        continue

if float(x) == int(x):  # looking for integers
    print('\nInteger Number')
    x = int(x)

else:
    print('\nFractional Number')
    x = float(x)
```